# Database datatype for Joomla Standard Form Field "usergrouplist"

Tags: joomla-3.x, mysql

What is the correct MySQL database datatype to be able to store the form data of the Joomla Standard Form Field [usergrouplist](https://docs.joomla.org/User_Group_List_form_field_type)?

Since Joomla 3.2 usergrouplist should be used instead of [usergroup](https://docs.joomla.org/Usergroup_form_field_type). As there is no documentation for usergrouplist so far I am wondering what's the correct `CREATE TABLE` statement to be able to store the form data in the database.

Serializing the form data and saving it to a text file shows that the form data is an array:

```
'usergrouplist_form_data' => 
  array (
    0 => '1',
    1 => '11',
  ),
```

An overview of all Joomla standard form field types can be found [here](https://docs.joomla.org/Standard_form_field_types).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usergrouplist is just a list of user group IDs in Joomla.

If you're going to save a single user group ID then any INT type (e.g. SMALLINT) should be fine.

However you can use this field (as any other list type) also with the option multiple=true. Then you have different options, for example set your column type to a TEXT type and save all values as JSON string or comma-separated list into it. Or you could use a third table with INT types again which would store the mappings of user group IDs to your data.

Comment: Yes, was able to make it work. Also came accross another answer from you which might be helpful to others dealing with this topic: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/9852/2238